# Faced Error "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError" while working with Apache Commons

Tags: java, tar, apache-commons

Used java program to test Apache commons (commons.compress and commons.io) using OpenJDK 1.6 in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. The build was OK but encountered error (below).
Both apache.commons.compress and apache.commons.io are in the same directory as program.

Command to build the program is as follows:
**javac unTar.java --module-path . --class-path . --add-modules org.apache.commons.io,org.apache.commons.compress**

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.*;
//import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveInputStream;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

public class unTar {  
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
                /* To read individual TAR file */
                TarArchiveEntry entry = null;
                String individualFiles;
                int offset;
                FileOutputStream outputFile=null;
                TarArchiveInputStream myTarFile=  new TarArchiveInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("tar_ball.tar")));
                /* Create a loop to read every single entry in TAR file */
                while ((entry = myTarFile.getNextTarEntry()) != null) {
                        /* Get the name of the file */
                        individualFiles = entry.getName();
                        /* Get Size of the file and create a byte array for the size */
                        byte[] content = new byte[(int) entry.getSize()];
                        offset=0;
                        /* Some SOP statements to check progress */
                        System.out.println("File Name in TAR File is: " + individualFiles);
                        System.out.println("Size of the File is: " + entry.getSize());
                        System.out.println("Byte Array length: " + content.length);
                        /* Read file from the archive into byte array */
                        myTarFile.read(content, offset, content.length - offset);
                        /* Define OutputStream for writing the file */
                        outputFile=new FileOutputStream(new File(individualFiles));
                        /* Use IOUtiles to write content of byte array to physical file */
                        IOUtils.write(content,outputFile);
                        /* Close Output Stream */
                        outputFile.close();
                }
                /* Close TarAchiveInputStream */
                myTarFile.close();
        }
}


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/tar/TarArchiveInputStream
    at unTar.main(unTar.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveInputStream
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)


    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: What is the command you have used to run the program? `java unTar`?

Answer (score 0):

```
java -cp commons-io-VERSION.jar:commons-compress-VERSION.jar unTar
```

Above is a regular way to provide the needed classpath to java runtime. Not sure if this is your issue.

Comment: Thanks. But it doesn't solve the problem. More intriguing is that I can managed to get commons-compress working now but not the commons-io-IOUtils, although they are in the same class path. The run time error is still java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils
I've also try placing the jar files in /usr/share/java. For that, class not found error during the compile time of commons-io-IOUtils.

Answer (score 0):

I was using a deprecated version of write. I changed to other alternatives and it worked. Sorry for the annoyance. I have not been doing Java for more than a decade.